# How can I build multiple queries at once with CodeIgniter QueryBuilder?

Tags: codeigniter

I have a complex `SELECT` with several time consuming calculated fields. I only want the first 100 rows, however, I also need the total rows found. This means executing the query once with `LIMIT` and once without.

I would like to be able to build two `SELECT`'s simultaneously with CodeIgniter's QueryBuilder and eliminate the time consuming calculated fields on the second query.

I would like to know if there is a good way to do this with QB or should I just build the `SELECT` without QB.

UPDATE: Apparently I have confused people. I need to do something like this:

To get the records to display:

```
SELECT id, [ several really time intensive calculated fields ]
FROM table
WHERE [some complicated criteria]
LIMIT 100;
```

To get the total records I would like to re-use the built query or build a 2nd one simultaneously but without the limit and with only the id field:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE [some complicated criteria];
```

Another option; I have learned that if I put the time intensive calculated fields in a sub SELECT, Postgres will not execute it until the row is actually retrieved.

For now I am manually building two queries but I'd like to do it the correct QueryBuilder way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to run multiple query in one statement in codeigniter. But you may do as following

```
$query1 = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 10');
$query2 = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table_name');
```

But what I do is make a method and call based on parameter like

```
public function get_rows($table, $num_rows = FALSE){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from($table);
  if($num_rows === FALSE){
    $this->db->limit(10);
  }

  $query = $this->db->get();
  if($num_rows){
    return $query->num_rows();
  }
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

Now you may call it as your requirements

```
//call for only count rows (without limit)
$this->model_name->get_rows('table_name', TRUE);

//call with limit for result rows
$this->model_name->get_rows('table_name');
```

Comment: This is quite far from the question but I do like your get_rows function. The goal is to either build two different queries simultaneously or execute one then change the SELECT portion of it and run it again without a limit.

Answer (score 0):

with count you can do this with query builder I think 
look at this code, you may want something like that

```
    if($limit != null){
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    }
    if($order_by != null){
        $this->db->order_by($order_by, $sort);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('courses');

    $courses['rows'] = $query->result();

    $courses['num_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('courses');

    return $courses;
```

Comment: I am not sure of this but I imagine CI simply re-runs the same query but without the limit. This means PSQL does the calculations for each field.